# Crypto api in linux kernel for AES error

Tags: linux, kernel, aes

I am doing encryption decryption using AES algorithm of cryptoAPI in linux kernel. The following code works fine if decryption is immediately done after encryption. But I wish to do this later and then its giving garbage. I am storing the encryption key for later decryption.

Code:

```
void encrypt(char *buf,u8 *key1)  
{    
    struct crypto_cipher *tfm;  
    int i,count,div,modd;  
    div=strlen(buf)/AES_BLOCK_SIZE;  
    modd=strlen(buf)%AES_BLOCK_SIZE;  
    if(modd>0)  
        div++;  
    count=div;  
    tfm=crypto_alloc_cipher("aes", 0, 16);    
    crypto_cipher_setkey(tfm,key1,16);    
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)  
    {  
        crypto_cipher_encrypt_one(tfm,buf,buf);      
        buf=buf+AES_BLOCK_SIZE;  
    }
    crypto_free_cipher(tfm);   
}
```

and:

```
void decrypt(char *buf,u8 *key1)
{  
    struct crypto_cipher *tfm;  
    int i,count,div,modd;  
    div=strlen(buf)/AES_BLOCK_SIZE;  
    modd=strlen(buf)%AES_BLOCK_SIZE;  
    if(modd>0)  
        div++;  
    count=div;  
    tfm=crypto_alloc_cipher("aes", 0, 16);  
    crypto_cipher_setkey(tfm,key1,16);  
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)  
    {  
        crypto_cipher_decrypt_one(tfm,buf,buf);   
        buf=buf+AES_BLOCK_SIZE;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: It's giving me garbage always. I am calling decrypt method just at the end of encrypt method. Any idea? How did you dod that when you said "works fine if decryption is immediately done after encryption"

Comment: Yes, same is happening with me too. Could you resolve the problem of 'only being able to decrypt just after encryption' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this api

`crypto_cipher_encrypt_one(tfm,dst,src);`

must diff dst from src.Maybe you can try to alloc dst[16].

I try to diff, and success.